# delete query doesn't work

Tags: php, pdo

I made a delete query. The delete query is used to delete posts made by the admin but if I click on the the delete button I go to a screen with object not found.
I will show the delete query:

```
    include '../db/db.php';

$id = $_GET['0'];

$query = "DELETE FROM pages WHERE paginaNummer = :id";
$stmt = $dbcon->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
$row=$stmt->fetch();

header("Location: http://127.0.0.1/cmsFenB/index.php");
```

Here is the db connection:

```
<?php

try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=register', 'root', '');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}   catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
?>
```

And here is the link that referrers to this script:

```
echo "&nbsp;<a class='delete' href='fucntions/admin/delete.php?id=" . $pageNumber . " '>Delete</a>";
```

I hope you can help me out with this problem.

Comment: Just comment this line `$row=$stmt->fetch();` you can't fetch data from delete query!! Also check `print_r($_GET['0'])` what it return!!

Comment: Add your error message here. ... with mentioned line.

Comment: ANd your db connection variable is `$db` not `$dbcon`

Comment: I don't get any error message, still got the object not found page

Comment: $dbcon <> $db - exactly what error message says

Comment: I made $dbcon to $db but I still go to the object not found page

Comment: What does the link look like that referrers to this script?

Comment: echo "&nbsp;<a class='delete' href='fucntions/admin/delete.php?id=" . $pageNumber . " '>Delete</a>"; this is the line of code that sends you to the delete script

Comment: take a look at my answer. You supposed to be using `$_GET['id']` instead of `$_GET['0']`

Comment: I tried it but didn't work out

Comment: What error do you get now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the referrer link. It should look like this:

```
echo "&nbsp;<a class='delete' href='functions/admin/delete.php?id=" . $pageNumber . " '>Delete</a>";
```

`$id=$_GET['0'];` ? I think you meant something like `$_GET['id']`

```
$id=$_GET['id'];

$query = "DELETE FROM pages WHERE paginaNummer = :id";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
```

Comment: I have tried it but it still gave me the object not found page

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other syntax errors in your code other than the code posted here?

Comment: I still get the object not found page no syntax error seen so far

Comment: What local sever are you on?

Comment: I am using xamp as my local server

Comment: Change this `echo "&nbsp;<a class='delete' href='fucntions/admin/delete.php?id=" . $pageNumber . " '>Delete</a>"; ` to this `echo "&nbsp;<a class='delete' href='functions/admin/delete.php?id=" . $pageNumber . " '>Delete</a>"; `